# Boolean algorithm producing true output when output should be false

Tags: java, string, algorithm, if-statement, for-loop

Basically i am trying to create an algorithm that will test whether a given string is a cover string for a list of strings. A string is a cover string if it contains the characters for every string in the list in a way that maintains the left to right order of the listed strings. For example, for the two strings "cat" and "dog", "cadhpotg" would be a cover string, but "ctadhpog" would not be one.

I have created an algorithm however it is producing the output true when the output should be false, as the given string is a cover String for Strings list1 and list2, but not for list3.

Any help into why this algorithm is producing the wrong output would be highly appreciated.

```
public class StringProcessing2 {

//ArrayList created and 3 fields added.
public static ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
public static String list1 = "phillip";
public static String list2 = "micky";  
public static String list3 = "fad"; 

//Algorithm to check whether given String is a cover string.
public static boolean isCover(String coverString){
    int matchedWords = 0;
    stringList.add(list1);
    stringList.add(list2);
    stringList.add(list3);

    //for-loops to iterate through each character of every word in stringList to test whether they appear in
    //coverString in left to right order.
    for(int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++){
    int countLetters = 1;
        for(int n = 0; n < (stringList.get(i).length())-1; n++){
            if(coverString.indexOf(stringList.get(i).charAt(n)) <= (coverString.indexOf((stringList.get(i).charAt(n+1)), 
                    coverString.indexOf((stringList.get(i).charAt(n)))))){
                countLetters++;
                if(countLetters == stringList.get(i).length()){
                matchedWords++;                     
                }                                  
            }               
        }
    }
if(matchedWords == stringList.size()){
    return true;
}
else
    return false;   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(isCover("phillmickyp"));

}


}
```

Comment: You should debug it using IDE. It'll help you learn. I would also start with an easier example to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Might want to [test drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) this. Lot of scope for regression errors here.

Comment: Think about the example `phillip`. This contains an `i` immediately before an `l` **and** an `l` immediately before an `i`. Think about why that makes things more tricky.

Comment: If your code was indented properly it would more clearly show that it does not make any sense as written. It would not even compile.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder Thank you for the suggestion. I am fairly new to coding, and when i attempt to debug my project by selecting "debug project" under the debug tab on netbeans, it simply outputs true with no errors, am i correctly debugging my project to test for errors?

Comment: @Mickd94 You can add a breakpoint at a line (usually click next to the line number) and see when you stop there what is the value of all variables and see step-by-step what happens and why.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to go about this is to break down the problem into parts.  Have every function do the least possible work while still getting something done towards the overall goal.

To accomplish this, I'd recommend creating a helper method that takes two Strings and returns a boolean, checking if one String is the cover of another.

```
boolean isCover(String s, String cover)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(char c : s.toCharArray())
    if((i = cover.indexOf(c, i)) == -1)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Then once you have something that can correctly tell you if it's a valid cover String or not, it becomes much simpler to check if one String is a valid cover for multiple Strings

```
boolean isCover(List<String> strings, String cover)
{
  for(String s : strings)
    if(!isCover(s, cover))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, i have never before seen the method of creating an advanced for loop or considered the concept of converting the string into a char array, which are both incredibly helpful tips.

Comment: I have never before seen an advanced for-loop, could you please explain to me the logic behind the first boolean, and how it ensures that the left to right order of the characters are maintained in the cover? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @Mickd94 The [for-each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) iterates over collections, in this case an array.  The for-each loop shows each value in the array one by one, starting at 0, in this case each char in the String.  The int is to save the last position of a found letter, as each new letter must be beyond the last, otherwise the cover string would be out of order.